# ggvis: x-axis with whole number scale

Tags: r, graph, scale, ggvis

I want to get whole numbers for x-axis for `ggvis` plot.

**MWE**

```
df <- 
  structure(list(Factor = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
  2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
  X = c(15.5133333333333, 14.63, 14.41, 14.1266666666667, 13.1833333333333, 
  12.9466666666667, 13.6133333333333, 13.55, 13.5333333333333, 
  11.5566666666667, 11.3066666666667, 11.4566666666667), Y = c(20L, 
  20L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), .Names = c("Factor", 
  "X", "Y"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggvis)

ggvis(data=df
      , x= ~X
      , y= ~Y
      , fill= ~Factor
      , stroke = ~Factor) %>% 
  arrange(Y) %>%
  group_by(Factor) %>%
  layer_points(shape=~Factor) %>% 
  layer_paths(fill := NA)  %>%
  add_axis('x', orient=c('bottom'), format='####')
```

[image]

One possibility is use `values=seq(from=10, to=16, by=1)` in `add_axis()`. But this is approach is not automated.

Comment: Maybe `seq(min(floor(df$X)),max(ceiling(df$X)),by=1)` then which is automated.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but `add_axis('x', orient=c('bottom'), format='d')` will use labels for *only* integer values, i.e. drop the in-between labels - here's the [`d3` reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting).

Comment: Thanks @LyzandeR and **nrussell** for your useful comments. `foramt='d'` is what I need for this `ggvis` graph. **nrussell** would you mind to change your comment to answer so that I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `format` argument to `'d'` will display only integer values in the axis label:

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)
##
ggvis(data=df
      , x= ~X
      , y= ~Y
      , fill= ~Factor
      , stroke = ~Factor) %>% 
  arrange(Y) %>%
  group_by(Factor) %>%
  layer_points(shape=~Factor) %>% 
  layer_paths(fill := NA)  %>%
  add_axis('x', orient=c('bottom'), format='d')
```

[image]

More information on `d3` formatting specifications is available on [this page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting), as mentioned in the *Common Properties* section of [this `ggvis` guide](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/axes-legends.html).